# Installation of valitron with composer on windows 7

Tags: windows, composer-php

I am trying to install valitron (https://github.com/vlucas/valitron) on Windows 8 but it doesn´t seems to work. It uses Composer (http://getcomposer.org) for installation, but documentation is quite poor.

Answer (score 0):

open the php shell console,  than enter "cd path/to/your/htdocs/project". then you only have to enter the following: "php path/to/your/composer.phar require vlucas/valitron *". This should work, I have tested it with Xampp Local Server.